# MongooseError: Cast to ObjectID failed for value on reading json for db seed

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, seeding

I have a model scheme with a reference field like this:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // ...
  uf:{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'UF', index: true
  },
});
```

And my test db seed code is consuming data from json files, like this:

```
[
  { "_id": 91283,
    "name":"Test user",
    "uf": 124411923,
    "version": 2
  }
]
```

During in the seed process, after the model save method, I’m getting this error:

```
ValidationError: User validation failed: uf: Cast to ObjectID failed for value "124411923" at path "uf"
errors:
{ uf:
   { MongooseError: Cast to ObjectID failed for value "124411923" at path "uf"
```

This is code responsible for loading the jsons and saving to the database, I've sorted the seed list so that UF is inserted first:

```
function seed() {
  console.log('Starting db seed...');

  return Promise.each(initialData, (data) => {
    // path to mongo model js file
    let Model = require(data.model);

    removeModel(Model)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('[' + data.name + '] model removed. ');
      return saveModel(data, Model);
    }).then(() => {
      console.log('[' + data.name + '] model saved');
    }).catch( (err) => {
      console.error('Error seeding db', err);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Saves model to the database
 * @param {*} data
 * @param {*} Model
 */
function saveModel(data, Model) {
  // path to json data file
  let seedList = require(data.seed);

  return Promise.map(seedList, function(seed) {
    let newItem = new Model(seed);
    return newItem.save({});
  });
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Just like the error says, `124411923` can't be cast to an ObjectId.

Comment: not helpful mate

Comment: Sorry, I'm just not sure what you're missing. You've defined `uf` in your schema as an ObjectId, but you're trying to put `124411923` into that field. There's no conversion for that.

Comment: I'm trying to understand mongodb concept of references. How can I reference another mongo document in a json? Like a foreign key.

Comment: You can read up on that [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

Answer (score 2):

In your user document, you are not including a valid ObjectId, hence the error when you try to store as type ObjectId.

Refs can only defence the _id field from other collections.

Therefore, in your user document, you will need to include a reference to the _id field from the UF collection:

```
[
    {
        "_id": 91283,
        "name":"Test user",
        "uf": [_id from UF here],
        "version": 2
    }
]
```

NOTE: If you have explicitly defined the _id field in your UF schema as type Number, then you can reference that from your user schema by matching types:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    // ...
    uf: {
        type: Number, ref: 'UF', index: true
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't have a valid ObjectId string. Try using `123456789012` as it's a 12 bytes string.